# Max Priority queue based on max-heap

Tags: heap, priority-queue

I am trying to implement the MAX-HEAP-INSERT(A,key) function. 
It's pseudocode is:

```
MAX-HEAP-INSERT(A,key)
  1 A.heap-size = A.heap-size+1
  2 A[A.heap-size] = -inf 
  3 HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,A.heap-size,key)
```

Where `HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,A.heap-size,key)` is another function which i didn't have trouble understanding.

The heap is based on an array A, and as we know arrays are limited. So, when we increase the `A.heap-size` won't there be a problem when `A.heap-size` gets bigger than `A.length`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If this happens you have to increase the size of your array.